# Proving that $aRb \iff a = b \lor a = b^2$ is antisymmetric.

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, relations

> Over $\mathbb{N}$, $aRb \iff a = b \lor a = b^2$.

I'm having problems determining if this relation is antisymmetric.

I think it is. I did the following:

---

### Direct proof attempt (got stucked)

We have to prove that $aRb \land bRa \implies a = b$.

Our premise is the fact that $aRb \land bRa$.

Based on our premise, we know that the following occurs:

$$(a = b \lor a = b^2) \land (b = a \lor b = a^2)$$

Distribute:

$$[(a = b \lor a = b^2) \land b = a] \lor [(a = b \lor a = b^2) \land b = a^2]$$

Absortion:

$$(a = b) \lor [(a = b \lor a = b^2) \land b = a^2]$$

Clearly I need to get rid of the rightmost part. But I'm not sure how. How can I proceed here?

---

### Proof by contradiction attempt (almost worked)

We have to prove that $aRb \land bRa \implies a = b$.

Our premise is the fact that $aRb \land bRa$.

Suppose that $a \not = b$.

Based on our premise, we know that the following occurs:
$$(a = b \lor a = b^2) \land (b = a \lor b = a^2)$$

Since we're supposing that $a \not = b$, it is simplified to

$$a = b^2 \land b = a^2$$

Alright, so this is where I'm not sure: **since $a \not = b$, can I affirm that the square of either number will always be *different* from the other number, in $\mathbb{R}?$** Because if that's the case, clearly $a = b^2 \land b = a^2$ won't hold, contradicting the premise, proving that it is indeed antisymmetric.

Comment: In both cases you switched from $\wedge$ to $\vee$ by accident.

Comment: Based on our premise, we know that the following occurs:
$$(a = b \lor a = b^2) \color{red}\lor (b = a \lor b = a^2)$$

Comment: Goodness. I'll try to correct it as soon as possible. Thank you.

Comment: Edited. Fortunately (or not), I still got stuck.

Comment: Since $a=b$ is equivalent to $b=a$ you end up with $a=b \vee (a=b^2 \wedge b=a^2)$, try to conclude $a=b$ in the second case.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Note that in $\Bbb N$ if $a=b^2$ then either $a=0$ or $a=1$ or $b<a$.

Answer (score 1):

The hypothesis “$a\mathrel{R}b$ and $b\mathrel{R}a$” splits into four cases:

- $a=b$ and $b=a$
- $a=b$ and $b=a^2$
- $a=b^2$ and $b=a$
- $a=b^2$ and $b=a^2$

The only case that needs work is the fourth one, where $a=a^4$, that is $a=0$ or $a=1$. But …

Comment: It is a bit unclear to me how did you split that into four cases. Could you elaborate on that? Thanks!

Comment: @Omega I just did $(A\lor B)\land(C\lor D)\equiv(A\land C)\lor(A\land D)\lor(B\land C)\lor(B\land D)$.